# Why I can't execute SQL query on Amazon Redshift from VPC private instance?

Tags: java, sql, amazon-vpc

I have an instance in a private subnet in an Amazon VPC. This instance uses a NAT to access the Internet.

I use the Redshift JDBC driver to connect to a cluster hosted in the same region as my VPC (us-east-1).

The `DriverManager.getConnection();` works and returns a connection. This should mean that the authentication succeeded. But when I execute the SQL Query via this code, the app hangs indefinitely without any error or success message:

```
Statement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users");
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
```

Why ?

Some details:

- I have tried outside the VPC and it works.
- I changed the DNS resolution servers in the instances (NAT and private instance)
- The same code locally on my machine works fine.
- The query is visible in Redshift and is aborted after 14 minutes.
- The same query takes 9 seconds when it is executed from my machine.
- I could not find any specific error in the logs of the instances.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the postgresql client from your VPC instance? I had the same issue and it was the security group applied to my instance.

Comment: Yes and the problem remained. We finally reached the AWS support team and the problem came from the MTU fixed for the network interface too high

Comment: Fscking MTU problems. Thanks for pointing this out, saved me a ton of trouble. I was using psql from the command line on an AWS m3.